# Android show Listview while typing

Tags: android, listview, searchview, custom-adapter

I have `Listview` with custom adapter. I put `Searchview` in activity bar to filter items in `Listview`. **Mycustom** `Listview` and `Searchview` working correctly.
I want my `Listview` start with empty, but just show items according to typing in `Searchview`

My Code Sample

MainActivity

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    btnsrc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);

    SeaFoodData food = new SeaFoodData(this);
    ArrayList<SeaFood> sList = new ArrayList<SeaFood>();

    try {
        sList = food.GetSeaFood();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     sfAdapter = new SeaFoodAdapter(MainActivity.this, sList);
     lv.setAdapter(sfAdapter); 

    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    filter = sfAdapter.getFilter();


}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText)
{

    filter.filter(newText);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    // Inflate menu to add items to action bar if it is present.
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    sv = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setQueryHint("Ara...");

    setupSearchView();

    return true;
}


private void setupSearchView()
{
    sv.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
}
```

My Adapter

```
    public SeaFoodAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<SeaFood> foodList) {
    super();
    this.context = ctx;
    this.seaFoodArrayList = foodList;

}




public class SeaFoodHolder
{
    TextView food;
    TextView description;
    ImageView rsm;

}

public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            final FilterResults oReturn = new FilterResults();
            final ArrayList<SeaFood> results = new ArrayList<SeaFood>();
            if (orig == null)
                orig = seaFoodArrayList;
            if (constraint != null) {
                if (orig != null && orig.size() > 0) {
                    for (final SeaFood g : orig) {
                        if (g.getName().toLowerCase()
                                .contains(constraint.toString()))
                            results.add(g);
                    }


                }
                oReturn.values = results;
            }
            return oReturn;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                      FilterResults results) {
            seaFoodArrayList = (ArrayList<SeaFood>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}

public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return seaFoodArrayList.size();
}

@Override
public SeaFood getItem(int position) {
    return seaFoodArrayList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    SeaFoodHolder holder;
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        convertView=LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        holder=new SeaFoodHolder();
        holder.food=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvFood);
        holder.description=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
        holder.rsm=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.warnimage);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder=(SeaFoodHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.food.setText(seaFoodArrayList.get(position).getName());
    holder.description.setText(String.valueOf(seaFoodArrayList.get(position).getDescription()));


    if (seaFoodArrayList.get(position).getimgPath().equals("0") ) {
        holder.rsm.setImageResource(R.drawable.error);
    } else {
        holder.rsm.setImageResource(R.drawable.check);
    }

    if (position % 2 == 0) {
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E3F2FD"));
    } else {
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#90CAF9"));
    }

    View vi = convertView;
    vi.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);

    return convertView;

}

public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu contextMenu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo contextMenuInfo) {
     // empty implementation
   }
```

SOLVED

I solved that problem.

Firstly,

I hide my Listview in On Create function after set adapter.

```
    sfAdapter = new SeaFoodAdapter(MainActivity.this, sList);
    lv.setAdapter(sfAdapter);

    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    filter = sfAdapter.getFilter();
    lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Then,

Show ListView according to search query in onQueryTextChange function

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText)
{

    if(newText == null || newText.equals(""))
    {
        lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else{
        lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    filter.filter(newText);

    return true;
}
```

Hope this will helpfull for someone. Thanks for help.

Comment: Initially load empty search list in ListView

Comment: I initially load empty list but i cant fill while typing

Comment: At least post your adapter code

Comment: 1. please paste your adapter code. 2. where is the data that you are planning to show, are you accessing it dynamically from DB or server ? OR you already have data with you in some list ?

Comment: I pasted code. I acces data from JSON file

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you, just want to show empty listview when there is nothing on the search field?

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
if(searchFieldTextView.getText() == null || searchFieldTextView.getText().equals(""))
{
    //Return empty view
}else{
    //Return your listview content
}
```

Is this making sense for you?

Hope this helps.

EDIT:

For accesing it just declare it static

in MainActivity

```
static SearchView searchField;
```

in your onCreateOptionsMenu just add

```
searchField = searchView;
```

or

```
searchfield = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
```

Then to access it just call

```
MainActivity.searchField
```

Comment: How can i reach searchFieldTextView from getView in Adapter

Comment: Cant find where are you obtaining the reference to the searchBar take a look at this http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html

Comment: I try but it reach it from 
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)

And use menu to get Searchview. Now the problem how can i reach Menu from getView Class

Comment: A simple solution is to store it in a static, basic java.

Comment: But public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) is in MainActivity.java 
And public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) is in SeaFoodAdapter.java
If is it ok for you can you give sample on my code which i shared above? How can i reach static field in MainActivity from SeaFoodAdapter

Comment: A static can be accesed from virtually anywhere, let me update the answer.

Comment: Thx for your help i can reach it now but getting error
 "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.getQuery()' on a null object reference."

searchFieldTextView.getText()  not work so i use searchFieldTextView.getQuery()

Comment: Make sure you are setting it before accesing it, using getQuery() is OK

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91868/discussion-between-omer-soyer-and-nanoc).